# Python - Binning x,y,z values on a 2D grid

Tags: python, binning

I have a list of `z` points associated to pairs `x,y`, meaning that for example

```
x     y                    z
3.1   5.2                  1.3    
4.2   2.3                  9.3
5.6   9.8                  3.5
```

and so on. The total number of `z` values is relatively high, around 10000.
I would like to bin my data, in the following sense:

1) I would like to split the `x` and `y` values into cells, so as to make a 2-dimensional grid in `x,y`.If I have `Nx` cells for the `x` axis and `Ny` for the `y` axis, I would then have `Nx*Ny` cells on the grid. For example, the first bin for `x` could be ranging from 1. to 2., the second from 2. to 3. and so on.

2) For each of this cell in the 2dimensional grid, I would then need to calculate how many points fall into that cell, and sum all their `z` values. This gives me a numerical value associated to each cell.

I thought about using `binned_statistic` from `scipy.stats`, but I would have no idea on how to set the options to accomplish my task. Any suggestions? Also other tools, other than `binned_statistic`, are well accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand, you can get what you need by exploiting the **expand_binnumbers** parameter for **binned_statistic_2d**, thus.

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_2d
import numpy as np

x = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6]
y = [2.1, 2.6, 2.1, 2.1]
z = [2.,3.,5.,7.]
binx = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
biny = [2.0, 2.5, 3.0]

ret = binned_statistic_2d(x, y, None, 'count', bins=[binx,biny], \
    expand_binnumbers=True)

print (ret.statistic)

print (ret.binnumber)

sums = np.zeros([-1+len(binx), -1+len(biny)])

for i in range(len(x)):
    m = ret.binnumber [0][i] - 1
    n = ret.binnumber [1][i] - 1
    sums[m][n] += sums[m][n] + z[i]

print (sums)
```

This is just an expansion of one of the examples. Here's the output.

```
[[ 2.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]]
[[1 1 1 2]
 [1 2 1 1]]
[[ 9.  3.]
 [ 7.  0.]]
```

Comment: Using this same example I'm strangely getting `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''` after calling `binned_statistic_2d`. Am I the only one ?

Comment: For the record, upgrading to scipy 1.5.0 fixed this issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

Establish the edges of the cells, iterate over cell edges and use boolean indexing to *extract* the z values in each cell, keep the sums in a list, convert the list and reshape it.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 1.2, 2.1])
y = np.array([2.1, 2.6, 2.1, 2.1, 3.4, 4.7])
z = np.array([2., 3., 5., 7., 10, 20])


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

minx, maxx = int(min(x)), int(max(x)) + 1
miny, maxy = int(min(y)), int(max(y)) + 1

result = []
x_edges = pairwise(xrange(minx, maxx + 1))
for xleft, xright in x_edges:
    xmask = np.logical_and(x >= xleft, x < xright)
    y_edges = pairwise(xrange(miny, maxy + 1))
    for yleft, yright in y_edges:
        ymask = np.logical_and(y >= yleft, y < yright)
        cell = z[np.logical_and(xmask, ymask)]
        result.append(cell.sum())

result = np.array(result).reshape((maxx - minx, maxy - miny))


>>> result
array([[ 17.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  10.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  20.]])
>>>
```

---

Unfortunately, no numpy vectorization magic